# Display entries made by authenticated user using model Manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I need to be able to display all the reservations made by the authenticated user on template. I am making use of a model Manager to override the get_queryset method to return the properties I need.

Then using it as the queryset in a view before passing it to the template. I don't know what I might be doing wrong as I followed the [documentation on managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/).

models.py

`class ReservationManager(models.Manager):`

```
  use_for_related_fields = True

  def get_queryset(self):
    return super(ReservationManager, self).get_queryset().filter(customer_name=User)
```

`class Reservation(models.Model):`

```
"""
this class will contain all information that concerns a car reservation
"""

customer_name = models.ForeignKey(User)
vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Car)
pickup_location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
drop_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='drop_location')
pickup_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
drop_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
reserved_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
edited_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

reservations = ReservationManager()
```

views.py

`class ReservationsList( ListView):`

```
model = Reservation
queryset = Reservation.reservations.all()
template_name = 'reservation_list.html'
context_object_name = 'reservations'
```

`

template

The template should display all the reservations made by the authenticated user.

```html
<tbody>

{% if user.is_authenticated  %}
            {% for reservation in reservations %}


<tr class="row1"><td class="action-checkbox"><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="2" /></td>
    <th class="field-code white-text grey center">{{reservation.code}}</th>
    <td class="field-customer_name nowrap">{{reservation.customer_name}}</td>
   
    <td class="field-vehicle nowrap">{{reservation.vehicle}}</td>
    <td class="field-pickup_location nowrap white-text grey center">{{reservation.pickup_location}}</td>
    <td class="field-drop_location nowrap">{{reservation.drop_location}}</td>
    <td class="field-pickup_time nowrap white-text grey center">{{reservation.pickup_time}}</td>
    <td class="field-drop_time nowrap ">{{reservation.drop_time}}</td>
    <td class="field-reserved_on white-text grey center nowrap">{{reservation.reserved_on}}</td>
</tr>


{% endfor %}

{% else %}
nothing
{% endif %}
</tbody>
```

What are my doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried an import pdb; pdb.set_trace() to see what is reservations bringing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to select on a property of the request (ie the current user), but a manager exists independently of requests.

Have you tried using a built-in class view? There, the equivalent get_queryset method is on a class instance that has available self.request and therefore self.request.user

Rewording the Django documentation example (at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/ ) slightly:

```
class ReservationList(ListView):

    template_name = 'reservation_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Reservation.objects.filter(customer=self.request.user)
```

I've just copied-pasted and then hacked the example, but hopefully it is close enough to working for you to make progress.